# Roof Replacement Done Wrong?

Tags: roof, roofing

I just had a new roof put on. It looks worse than the old. I have three areas of concern. It was put on in cold weather so that may explain the shingles, but the bigger bumps and dips are concerning.

The board by "C" is just to show the dip. "A" is where we extended the roof, but they said it would be flat on the re-roof.

[image]

Comment: You really need an independent inspector to examine this, and possibly to be a witness if you need to take legal action.

Comment: There's a lack of clarity here about what's new and what's old. OP hasn't been back. Voting to close.